# Вывод подобного окна через php

Tags: php

Прошу прощения, я довольно плохо разбираюсь в пхп.
Нужно чтоб при входе на страницу, php после некоторых действий показывал подобное окно вверху сайта. на чем оно будет написано,  в принцыпи не имеет значения. Нет у кого кода для такой штуки? пол инета обыскал, и не нашел.. хотя, возможно я просто не смог нормально сформулировать вопрос. [image: Пример соообщения]

Comment: В javascript есть вот это https://myrusakov.ru/js-prompt.html

Comment: Bootstrap - модальные окна.

Comment: @Quazimorda тут немного не то, мне надо чтоб по нажатию по кнопке, происходило действие а не просто закрытие окна)

Comment: Так если использовать окно типа prompt, то при нажатии на кнопку, окно закроется, но строку с данными можно будет получить и далее их использовать по вашему усмотрению.

Comment: @Quazimorda обьясняю:
появляется окно, в нем написано про инструкцию. 
нажимаешь на кнопку, открывается инструкция

Comment: Это фронтенд, и php тут ни при чём

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам модальное окно с 2-мя кнопками (кнопка для закрытия модального окна и кнопка для открытия инструкции): https://codepen.io/unzerstorbar/pen/qBZXwjw (код в конце ответа)

[image: Вот такое вот модальное окно получилось]

Всё достаточно просто:
Взял модальное окно на Bootstrap и кнопку обернул кнопку ссылкой

P.S. Что бы всё было красиво и работало - обрати внимание на то что в Настройках я подключил 1 css и 3 js файла (все bootstrap'овские)

```
<!-- Кнопка для запуска модального окна -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Открыть модальное окно
</button>

<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ВНИМАНИЕ!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Текст
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" targer="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо кончено, но вот тут и встретилась та самая проблема: модальное окно должно активироваться не по нажатию кнопки, а через пхп. Приблизительно так: проверка наличия файла, если он есть - показать окно, удалить файл